# How to use a for loop in gnuplot with a grep command

Tags: awk, grep, gnuplot

I have a large data file and I want to plot it in gnuplot with a particular data set.
say my file is with this type (posting few top rows only)

```
  -0.00098   50.0000    -73.62733500  0.37741253E+21  0.61856999E+04  0.23477516E+05  0.61856999E+04  0.37741253E+21  0.22799744E+05  0.23477516E+05  0.22799744E+05  0.32885992E+21  0.88623333E-05  0.9143
4842E-22  0.59361518E-21  0.91434842E-22  0.88623333E-05  0.76940601E-21 -0.11008087E-21  0.61205532E-22  0.18946967E-04  0.46510926E+15  0.84479535E-02  0.32276586E-01  0.84479535E-02  0.46510926E+15  0.
31473355E-01  0.32276586E-01  0.31473355E-01  0.44827543E+15
  -0.00098  100.0000    -73.62549799  0.37578210E+21  0.65089174E+04  0.25164304E+05  0.65089174E+04  0.37578210E+21  0.24544833E+05  0.25164304E+05  0.24544833E+05  0.35067726E+21  0.51668308E-05  0.1764
9563E-21  0.80398976E-21  0.17649563E-21  0.51668308E-05  0.89345101E-21  0.73256391E-24  0.10266879E-21  0.16359894E-04  0.88915594E+15  0.15704246E-01  0.66816427E-01  0.15704246E-01  0.88915594E+15  0.
65852810E-01  0.66816427E-01  0.65852810E-01  0.92442123E+15
  -0.00098  150.0000    -73.62497753  0.37191742E+21  0.64483669E+04  0.25884494E+05  0.64483669E+04  0.37191742E+21  0.25340696E+05  0.25884494E+05  0.25340696E+05  0.35980685E+21 -0.23512396E-05  0.1633
1744E-21  0.58153481E-21  0.16331744E-21 -0.23512396E-05  0.60771148E-21  0.50286216E-22  0.86373493E-22  0.50098427E-05  0.13431409E+16  0.20196300E-01  0.99364940E-01  0.20196300E-01  0.13431409E+16  0.
97983721E-01  0.99364940E-01  0.97983721E-01  0.13754518E+16
  -0.00098  200.0000    -73.62563644  0.37048872E+21  0.62302191E+04  0.26197599E+05  0.62302191E+04  0.37048872E+21  0.25696216E+05  0.26197599E+05  0.25696216E+05  0.36375679E+21 -0.63534979E-05  0.1937
3109E-21  0.35080011E-21  0.19373109E-21 -0.63534979E-05  0.34652203E-21  0.74754878E-22  0.75715625E-22 -0.25397863E-05  0.18008807E+16  0.23385420E-01  0.13054336E+00  0.23385420E-01  0.18008807E+16  0.
12878815E+00  0.13054336E+00  0.12878815E+00  0.18120888E+16
  -0.00098  250.0000    -73.62700262  0.37004605E+21  0.59702233E+04  0.26319789E+05  0.59702233E+04  0.37004605E+21  0.25845805E+05  0.26319789E+05  0.25845805E+05  0.36538123E+21 -0.87562569E-05  0.2350
8035E-21  0.21794599E-21  0.23508035E-21 -0.87562569E-05  0.20313466E-21  0.86523972E-22  0.74216616E-22 -0.69471421E-05  0.22540241E+16  0.26857802E-01  0.16135874E+00  0.26857802E-01  0.22540241E+16  0.
15941431E+00  0.16135874E+00  0.15941431E+00  0.22455089E+16
  -0.00098  300.0000    -73.62885616  0.36987141E+21  0.57283989E+04  0.26353384E+05  0.57283989E+04  0.36987141E+21  0.25902439E+05  0.26353384E+05  0.25902439E+05  0.36594140E+21 -0.10680927E-04  0.2650
9374E-21  0.16112721E-21  0.26509374E-21 -0.10680927E-04  0.14526557E-21  0.94641866E-22  0.80057120E-22 -0.97718295E-05  0.27036601E+16  0.31147309E-01  0.19222339E+00  0.31147309E-01  0.27036601E+16  0.
19021091E+00  0.19222339E+00  0.19021091E+00  0.26798788E+16
  -0.00098  350.0000    -73.63111766  0.36975138E+21  0.55256178E+04  0.26348308E+05  0.55256178E+04  0.36975138E+21  0.25919105E+05  0.26348308E+05  0.25919105E+05  0.36603300E+21 -0.12473836E-04  0.2799
1651E-21  0.14542677E-21  0.27991651E-21 -0.12473836E-04  0.13260173E-21  0.10349056E-21  0.91453794E-22 -0.11905859E-04  0.31506980E+16  0.36215123E-01  0.22310409E+00  0.36215123E-01  0.31506980E+16  0.
22106737E+00  0.22310409E+00  0.22106737E+00  0.31144960E+16
  -0.00098  400.0000    -73.63376390  0.36962941E+21  0.53639569E+04  0.26326807E+05  0.53639569E+04  0.36962941E+21  0.25918318E+05  0.26326807E+05  0.25918318E+05  0.36591763E+21 -0.14220403E-04  0.2831
3619E-21  0.14955855E-21  0.28313619E-21 -0.14220403E-04  0.14127110E-21  0.11444368E-21  0.10676100E-21 -0.13748475E-04  0.35950954E+16  0.41845525E-01  0.25383427E+00  0.41845525E-01  0.35950954E+16  0.
25177268E+00  0.25383427E+00  0.25177268E+00  0.35473558E+16
  -0.00098  450.0000    -73.63679316  0.36948970E+21  0.52383588E+04  0.26297916E+05  0.52383588E+04  0.36948970E+21  0.25908795E+05  0.26297916E+05  0.25908795E+05  0.36570139E+21 -0.15936631E-04  0.2795
7578E-21  0.16328981E-21  0.27957578E-21 -0.15936631E-04  0.15979750E-21  0.12755049E-21  0.12459804E-21 -0.15458011E-04  0.40362355E+16  0.47818758E-01  0.28423315E+00  0.47818758E-01  0.40362355E+16  0.
28212874E+00  0.28423315E+00  0.28212874E+00  0.39763635E+16
  -0.00098  500.0000    -73.64021237  0.36932598E+21  0.51419673E+04  0.26264871E+05  0.51419673E+04  0.36932598E+21  0.25893531E+05  0.26264871E+05  0.25893531E+05  0.36542326E+21 -0.17621860E-04  0.2731
0103E-21  0.18212730E-21  0.27310103E-21 -0.17621860E-04  0.18309310E-21  0.14241596E-21  0.14390579E-21 -0.17090518E-04  0.44731808E+16  0.53962381E-01  0.31413040E+00  0.53962381E-01  0.44731808E+16  0.
31196260E+00  0.31413040E+00  0.31196260E+00  0.43994976E+16
  -0.00098  550.0000    -73.64403198  0.36913386E+21  0.50682689E+04  0.26228510E+05  0.50682689E+04  0.36913386E+21  0.25873289E+05  0.26228510E+05  0.25873289E+05  0.36509452E+21 -0.19271791E-04  0.2662
3467E-21  0.20413816E-21  0.26623467E-21 -0.19271791E-04  0.20896167E-21  0.15856269E-21  0.16392041E-21 -0.18661811E-04  0.49048167E+16  0.60155238E-01  0.34336735E+00  0.60155238E-01  0.49048167E+16  0.
34111935E+00  0.34336735E+00  0.34111935E+00  0.48147808E+16
  -0.00098  600.0000    -73.64826334  0.36890914E+21  0.50117933E+04  0.26188726E+05  0.50117933E+04  0.36890914E+21  0.25848018E+05  0.26188726E+05  0.25848018E+05  0.36471534E+21 -0.20881700E-04  0.2603
7843E-21  0.22846098E-21  0.26037843E-21 -0.20881700E-04  0.23645575E-21  0.17555634E-21  0.18411472E-21 -0.20173041E-04  0.53299487E+16  0.66317761E-01  0.37179746E+00  0.66317761E-01  0.53299487E+16  0.
36945793E+00  0.37179746E+00  0.36945793E+00  0.52202929E+16
  -0.00098  650.0000    -73.65291720  0.36864759E+21  0.49682077E+04  0.26145083E+05  0.49682077E+04  0.36864759E+21  0.25817410E+05  0.26145083E+05  0.25817410E+05  0.36428161E+21 -0.22447322E-04  0.2561
5116E-21  0.25466854E-21  0.25615116E-21 -0.22447322E-04  0.26515795E-21  0.19303776E-21  0.20413756E-21 -0.21620851E-04  0.57473738E+16  0.72400690E-01  0.39928880E+00  0.72400690E-01  0.57473738E+16  0.
39685170E+00  0.39928880E+00  0.39685170E+00  0.56142317E+16
  -0.00098  700.0000    -73.65800250  0.36834508E+21  0.49341868E+04  0.26097070E+05  0.49341868E+04  0.36834508E+21  0.25781111E+05  0.26097070E+05  0.25781111E+05  0.36378791E+21 -0.23965126E-04  0.2536
8118E-21  0.28250178E-21  0.25368118E-21 -0.23965126E-04  0.29486863E-21  0.21072212E-21  0.22376269E-21 -0.23001329E-04  0.61559302E+16  0.78375584E-01  0.42572703E+00  0.78375584E-01  0.61559302E+16  0.
42319066E+00  0.42572703E+00  0.42319066E+00  0.59949801E+16
  -0.00098  750.0000    -73.66352576  0.36799775E+21  0.49072227E+04  0.26044213E+05  0.49072227E+04  0.36799775E+21  0.25738807E+05  0.26044213E+05  0.25738807E+05  0.36322879E+21 -0.25432369E-04  0.2528
1878E-21  0.31175849E-21  0.25281878E-21 -0.25432369E-04  0.32546713E-21  0.22838818E-21  0.24284943E-21 -0.24311455E-04  0.65545284E+16  0.84227621E-01  0.45101738E+00  0.84227621E-01  0.65545284E+16  0.
44838335E+00  0.45101738E+00  0.44838335E+00  0.63611571E+16
  -0.00098  800.0000    -73.66949059  0.36760215E+21  0.48854421E+04  0.25986115E+05  0.48854421E+04  0.36760215E+21  0.25690254E+05  0.25986115E+05  0.25690254E+05  0.36259943E+21 -0.26847058E-04  0.2532
7757E-21  0.34224719E-21  0.25327757E-21 -0.26847058E-04  0.35684931E-21  0.24586617E-21  0.26131387E-21 -0.25549530E-04  0.69421686E+16  0.89950399E-01  0.47508540E+00  0.89950399E-01  0.69421686E+16  0.
47235776E+00  0.47508540E+00  0.47235776E+00  0.67116424E+16
  -0.00093   50.0000    -73.62977019  0.37577464E+21  0.61553734E+04  0.23285918E+05  0.61553734E+04  0.37577464E+21  0.22570271E+05  0.23285918E+05  0.22570271E+05  0.32568177E+21  0.86963846E-05  0.7152
3652E-22  0.52597500E-21  0.71523652E-22  0.86963846E-05  0.70496949E-21 -0.11810836E-21  0.54664950E-22  0.17958746E-04  0.46250691E+15  0.83132601E-02  0.31933229E-01  0.83132601E-02  0.46250691E+15  0.
31151664E-01  0.31933229E-01  0.31151664E-01  0.44409835E+15
  -0.00093  100.0000    -73.62798627  0.37476731E+21  0.64692520E+04  0.25007969E+05  0.64692520E+04  0.37476731E+21  0.24377200E+05  0.25007969E+05  0.24377200E+05  0.34845318E+21  0.53423675E-05  0.1713
3713E-21  0.75479441E-21  0.17133713E-21  0.53423675E-05  0.84146003E-21 -0.22647358E-23  0.96074049E-22  0.15893375E-04  0.89382697E+15  0.15795329E-01  0.67149566E-01  0.15795329E-01  0.89382697E+15  0.
66214050E-01  0.67149566E-01  0.66214050E-01  0.92957900E+15
  -0.00093  150.0000    -73.62747497  0.37185376E+21  0.64337148E+04  0.25825768E+05  0.64337148E+04  0.37185376E+21  0.25278107E+05  0.25825768E+05  0.25278107E+05  0.35902397E+21 -0.22740554E-05  0.1676
0534E-21  0.55794765E-21  0.16760534E-21 -0.22740554E-05  0.58205475E-21  0.48726045E-22  0.82391713E-22  0.47808216E-05  0.13473342E+16  0.20257500E-01  0.99839308E-01  0.20257500E-01  0.13473342E+16  0.
98484660E-01  0.99839308E-01  0.98484660E-01  0.13824225E+16
  -0.00093  200.0000    -73.62813929  0.37074725E+21  0.62240793E+04  0.26186874E+05  0.62240793E+04  0.37074725E+21  0.25684501E+05  0.26186874E+05  0.25684501E+05  0.36366013E+21 -0.63245921E-05  0.2022
4040E-21  0.34077370E-21  0.20224040E-21 -0.63245921E-05  0.33528141E-21  0.74144816E-22  0.73747595E-22 -0.26419524E-05  0.18038200E+16  0.23388093E-01  0.13092954E+00  0.23388093E-01  0.18038200E+16  0.
12918874E+00  0.13092954E+00  0.12918874E+00  0.18176804E+16
  -0.00093  250.0000    -73.62950993  0.37038936E+21  0.59658990E+04  0.26329238E+05  0.59658990E+04  0.37038936E+21  0.25855227E+05  0.26329238E+05  0.25855227E+05  0.36556576E+21 -0.87397171E-05  0.2439
1671E-21  0.21417453E-21  0.24391671E-21 -0.87397171E-05  0.19847913E-21  0.86454004E-22  0.73212165E-22 -0.69822324E-05  0.22566213E+16  0.26845644E-01  0.16165253E+00  0.26845644E-01  0.22566213E+16  0.
15971111E+00  0.16165253E+00  0.15971111E+00  0.22497456E+16
  -0.00093  300.0000    -73.63136730  0.37023446E+21  0.57244337E+04  0.26370893E+05  0.57244337E+04  0.37023446E+21  0.25920135E+05  0.26370893E+05  0.25920135E+05  0.36623411E+21 -0.10665783E-04  0.2727
0077E-21  0.15999813E-21  0.27270077E-21 -0.10665783E-04  0.14334688E-21  0.94817413E-22  0.79430659E-22 -0.97749483E-05  0.27064230E+16  0.31148260E-01  0.19246677E+00  0.31148260E-01  0.27064230E+16  0.
19044950E+00  0.19246677E+00  0.19044950E+00  0.26834343E+16
  -0.00093  350.0000    -73.63363251  0.37011834E+21  0.55219962E+04  0.26368956E+05  0.55219962E+04  0.37011834E+21  0.25939889E+05  0.26368956E+05  0.25939889E+05  0.36636548E+21 -0.12457200E-04  0.2859
4081E-21  0.14534323E-21  0.28594081E-21 -0.12457200E-04  0.13176599E-21  0.10374811E-21  0.90961379E-22 -0.11894050E-04  0.31537973E+16  0.36237822E-01  0.22332990E+00  0.36237822E-01  0.31537973E+16  0.
22128370E+00  0.22332990E+00  0.22128370E+00  0.31178832E+16
  -0.00093  400.0000    -73.63628270  0.36999656E+21  0.53608727E+04  0.26348637E+05  0.53608727E+04  0.36999656E+21  0.25940158E+05  0.26348637E+05  0.25940158E+05  0.36626387E+21 -0.14201523E-04  0.2876
9320E-21  0.14986192E-21  0.28769320E-21 -0.14201523E-04  0.14085974E-21  0.11470565E-21  0.10631587E-21 -0.13729077E-04  0.35985666E+16  0.41888424E-01  0.25406018E+00  0.41888424E-01  0.35985666E+16  0.
25198667E+00  0.25406018E+00  0.25198667E+00  0.35508463E+16
  -0.00093  450.0000    -73.63931639  0.36985607E+21  0.52359300E+04  0.26320141E+05  0.52359300E+04  0.36985607E+21  0.25930902E+05  0.26320141E+05  0.25930902E+05  0.36605165E+21 -0.15915274E-04  0.2829
2019E-21  0.16372312E-21  0.28292019E-21 -0.15915274E-04  0.15956261E-21  0.12778551E-21  0.12417436E-21 -0.15433937E-04  0.40400685E+16  0.47876628E-01  0.28446661E+00  0.47876628E-01  0.40400685E+16  0.
28234938E+00  0.28446661E+00  0.28234938E+00  0.39800681E+16
  -0.00093  500.0000    -73.64274063  0.36969117E+21  0.51402142E+04  0.26287162E+05  0.51402142E+04  0.36969117E+21  0.25915592E+05  0.26287162E+05  0.25915592E+05  0.36577383E+21 -0.17597906E-04  0.2754
9537E-21  0.18259769E-21  0.27549537E-21 -0.17597906E-04  0.18294720E-21  0.14261481E-21  0.14349843E-21 -0.17062815E-04  0.44773500E+16  0.54029595E-01  0.31437329E+00  0.54029595E-01  0.44773500E+16  0.
31219283E+00  0.31437329E+00  0.31219283E+00  0.44034399E+16
  -0.00093  550.0000    -73.64656592  0.36949760E+21  0.50671478E+04  0.26250714E+05  0.50671478E+04  0.36949760E+21  0.25895174E+05  0.26250714E+05  0.25895174E+05  0.36544387E+21 -0.19245142E-04  0.2679
0438E-21  0.20461749E-21  0.26790438E-21 -0.19245142E-04  0.20887735E-21  0.15872565E-21  0.16352994E-21 -0.18630779E-04  0.49092895E+16  0.60227106E-01  0.34361874E+00  0.60227106E-01  0.49092895E+16  0.
34135892E+00  0.34361874E+00  0.34135892E+00  0.48189407E+16
  -0.00093  600.0000    -73.65080369  0.36927118E+21  0.50112286E+04  0.26210761E+05  0.50112286E+04  0.36927118E+21  0.25869669E+05  0.26210761E+05  0.25869669E+05  0.36506268E+21 -0.20852261E-04  0.2615
0237E-21  0.22894553E-21  0.26150237E-21 -0.20852261E-04  0.23642687E-21  0.17568706E-21  0.18374226E-21 -0.20138688E-04  0.53346889E+16  0.66390898E-01  0.37205511E+00  0.66390898E-01  0.53346889E+16  0.
36970504E+00  0.37205511E+00  0.36970504E+00  0.52246301E+16
  -0.00093  650.0000    -73.65546466  0.36900768E+21  0.49681140E+04  0.26166898E+05  0.49681140E+04  0.36900768E+21  0.25838796E+05  0.26166898E+05  0.25838796E+05  0.36462644E+21 -0.22415005E-04  0.2568
6558E-21  0.25516285E-21  0.25686558E-21 -0.22415005E-04  0.26518500E-21  0.19314055E-21  0.20378341E-21 -0.21583085E-04  0.57523434E+16  0.72472944E-01  0.39954993E+00  0.72472944E-01  0.57523434E+16  0.
39710377E+00  0.39954993E+00  0.39710377E+00  0.56186973E+16
  -0.00093  700.0000    -73.66055778  0.36870295E+21  0.49344813E+04  0.26118629E+05  0.49344813E+04  0.36870295E+21  0.25802213E+05  0.26118629E+05  0.25802213E+05  0.36412980E+21 -0.23929854E-04  0.2540
8759E-21  0.28301226E-21  0.25408759E-21 -0.23929854E-04  0.29495343E-21  0.21080085E-21  0.22342621E-21 -0.22960037E-04  0.61610906E+16  0.78445803E-01  0.42598868E+00  0.78445803E-01  0.61610906E+16  0.
42344481E+00  0.42598868E+00  0.42344481E+00  0.59995232E+16
  -0.00093  750.0000    -73.66608950  0.36835316E+21  0.49078313E+04  0.26065489E+05  0.49078313E+04  0.36835316E+21  0.25759609E+05  0.26065489E+05  0.25759609E+05  0.36356738E+21 -0.25394082E-04  0.2529
9193E-21  0.31229095E-21  0.25299193E-21 -0.25394082E-04  0.32561094E-21  0.22844604E-21  0.24252927E-21 -0.24266538E-04  0.65598409E+16  0.84295403E-01  0.45127671E+00  0.84295403E-01  0.65598409E+16  0.
44863671E+00  0.45127671E+00  0.44863671E+00  0.63657280E+16
  -0.00093  800.0000    -73.67206337  0.36795486E+21  0.48863016E+04  0.26007083E+05  0.48863016E+04  0.36795486E+21  0.25710742E+05  0.26007083E+05  0.25710742E+05  0.36293437E+21 -0.26805713E-04  0.2532
7229E-21  0.34280603E-21  0.25327229E-21 -0.26805713E-04  0.35705226E-21  0.24590563E-21  0.26100832E-21 -0.25500918E-04  0.69475951E+16  0.90015851E-01  0.47533975E+00  0.90015851E-01  0.69475951E+16  0.
47260759E+00  0.47533975E+00  0.47260759E+00  0.67161950E+16
  -0.00088   50.0000    -73.63219428  0.37418236E+21  0.61311700E+04  0.23109988E+05  0.61311700E+04  0.37418236E+21  0.22356056E+05  0.23109988E+05  0.22356056E+05  0.32270480E+21  0.86013329E-05  0.5525
6665E-22  0.46027248E-21  0.55256665E-22  0.86013329E-05  0.64014524E-21 -0.12353787E-21  0.48569415E-22  0.17028764E-04  0.45982260E+15  0.81727432E-02  0.31599025E-01  0.81727432E-02  0.45982260E+15  0.
30841926E-01  0.31599025E-01  0.30841926E-01  0.44006283E+15
  -0.00088  100.0000    -73.63046660  0.37373730E+21  0.64305446E+04  0.24858504E+05  0.64305446E+04  0.37373730E+21  0.24216928E+05  0.24858504E+05  0.24216928E+05  0.34631993E+21  0.54702932E-05  0.1658
5544E-21  0.70371007E-21  0.16585544E-21  0.54702932E-05  0.78698173E-21 -0.48552261E-23  0.89262698E-22  0.15347130E-04  0.89850207E+15  0.15880313E-01  0.67465074E-01  0.15880313E-01  0.89850207E+15  0.
66557114E-01  0.67465074E-01  0.66557114E-01  0.93449675E+15
  -0.00088  150.0000    -73.62997106  0.37178121E+21  0.64189202E+04  0.25769357E+05  0.64189202E+04  0.37178121E+21  0.25218083E+05  0.25769357E+05  0.25218083E+05  0.35827087E+21 -0.22175581E-05  0.1717
1257E-21  0.53312586E-21  0.17171257E-21 -0.22175581E-05  0.55495686E-21  0.47262063E-22  0.78279193E-22  0.45126183E-05  0.13515816E+16  0.20313928E-01  0.10030165E+00  0.20313928E-01  0.13515816E+16  0.
98972467E-01  0.10030165E+00  0.98972467E-01  0.13892382E+16
  -0.00088  200.0000    -73.63064344  0.37100313E+21  0.62174829E+04  0.26177025E+05  0.62174829E+04  0.37100313E+21  0.25673768E+05  0.26177025E+05  0.25673768E+05  0.36357466E+21 -0.63016000E-05  0.2106
9518E-21  0.33004815E-21  0.21069518E-21 -0.63016000E-05  0.32327519E-21  0.73553769E-22  0.71720514E-22 -0.27600033E-05  0.18067844E+16  0.23389184E-01  0.13130795E+00  0.23389184E-01  0.18067844E+16  0.
12958097E+00  0.13130795E+00  0.12958097E+00  0.18231754E+16
  -0.00088  250.0000    -73.63201945  0.37073193E+21  0.59611054E+04  0.26339008E+05  0.59611054E+04  0.37073193E+21  0.25865024E+05  0.26339008E+05  0.25865024E+05  0.36575452E+21 -0.87246423E-05  0.2527
2511E-21  0.21006243E-21  0.25272511E-21 -0.87246423E-05  0.19346653E-21  0.86377627E-22  0.72179562E-22 -0.70234263E-05  0.22592267E+16  0.26834422E-01  0.16194190E+00  0.26834422E-01  0.22592267E+16  0.
16000327E+00  0.16194190E+00  0.16000327E+00  0.22539280E+16
  -0.00088  300.0000    -73.63388094  0.37059725E+21  0.57200805E+04  0.26388504E+05  0.57200805E+04  0.37059725E+21  0.25937968E+05  0.26388504E+05  0.25937968E+05  0.36652831E+21 -0.10650982E-04  0.2802
7615E-21  0.15871828E-21  0.28027615E-21 -0.10650982E-04  0.14127829E-21  0.94981648E-22  0.78791576E-22 -0.97803455E-05  0.27091876E+16  0.31151464E-01  0.19270788E+00  0.31151464E-01  0.27091876E+16  0.
19068573E+00  0.19270788E+00  0.19068573E+00  0.26869618E+16
  -0.00088  350.0000    -73.63614996  0.37048515E+21  0.55180785E+04  0.26389620E+05  0.55180785E+04  0.37048515E+21  0.25960717E+05  0.26389620E+05  0.25960717E+05  0.36669836E+21 -0.12440648E-04  0.2919
2701E-21  0.14519602E-21  0.29192701E-21 -0.12440648E-04  0.13087283E-21  0.10399632E-21  0.90465017E-22 -0.11883078E-04  0.31568961E+16  0.36263232E-01  0.22355459E+00  0.36263232E-01  0.31568961E+16  0.
22149884E+00  0.22355459E+00  0.22149884E+00  0.31212561E+16
  -0.00088  400.0000    -73.63880416  0.37036359E+21  0.53575705E+04  0.26370453E+05  0.53575705E+04  0.37036359E+21  0.25962009E+05  0.26370453E+05  0.25962009E+05  0.36661010E+21 -0.14182669E-04  0.2922
0978E-21  0.15013898E-21  0.29220978E-21 -0.14182669E-04  0.14042935E-21  0.11496157E-21  0.10587162E-21 -0.13709985E-04  0.36020363E+16  0.41934011E-01  0.25428552E+00  0.41934011E-01  0.36020363E+16  0.
25219999E+00  0.25428552E+00  0.25219999E+00  0.35543290E+16
  -0.00088  450.0000    -73.64184230  0.37022231E+21  0.52333430E+04  0.26342343E+05  0.52333430E+04  0.37022231E+21  0.25953006E+05  0.26342343E+05  0.25953006E+05  0.36640177E+21 -0.15893927E-04  0.2862
2579E-21  0.16414594E-21  0.28622579E-21 -0.15893927E-04  0.15932400E-21  0.12801731E-21  0.12375407E-21 -0.15409973E-04  0.40438995E+16  0.47936929E-01  0.28469972E+00  0.47936929E-01  0.40438995E+16  0.
28256954E+00  0.28469972E+00  0.28256954E+00  0.39837674E+16
  -0.00088  500.0000    -73.64527159  0.37005624E+21  0.51383471E+04  0.26309427E+05  0.51383471E+04  0.37005624E+21  0.25937643E+05  0.26309427E+05  0.25937643E+05  0.36612421E+21 -0.17573957E-04  0.2778
5495E-21  0.18306450E-21  0.27785495E-21 -0.17573957E-04  0.18280354E-21  0.14281249E-21  0.14309562E-21 -0.17035150E-04  0.44815165E+16  0.54098895E-01  0.31461586E+00  0.54098895E-01  0.44815165E+16  0.
31242259E+00  0.31461586E+00  0.31242259E+00  0.44073774E+16
  -0.00088  550.0000    -73.64910260  0.36986122E+21  0.50659443E+04  0.26272890E+05  0.50659443E+04  0.36986122E+21  0.25917047E+05  0.26272890E+05  0.25917047E+05  0.36579299E+21 -0.19218494E-04  0.2695
4434E-21  0.20509650E-21  0.26954434E-21 -0.19218494E-04  0.20879750E-21  0.15888880E-21  0.16314438E-21 -0.18599755E-04  0.49137589E+16  0.60300709E-01  0.34386977E+00  0.60300709E-01  0.49137589E+16  0.
34159799E+00  0.34386977E+00  0.34159799E+00  0.48230954E+16
  -0.00088  600.0000    -73.65334679  0.36963309E+21  0.50106041E+04  0.26232768E+05  0.50106041E+04  0.36963309E+21  0.25891307E+05  0.26232768E+05  0.25891307E+05  0.36540978E+21 -0.20822820E-04  0.2626
0163E-21  0.22943144E-21  0.26260163E-21 -0.20822820E-04  0.23640317E-21  0.17581883E-21  0.18337464E-21 -0.20104328E-04  0.53394250E+16  0.66465448E-01  0.37231234E+00  0.66465448E-01  0.53394250E+16  0.
36995156E+00  0.37231234E+00  0.36995156E+00  0.52289612E+16
  -0.00088  650.0000    -73.65801490  0.36936762E+21  0.49679766E+04  0.26188686E+05  0.49679766E+04  0.36936762E+21  0.25860167E+05  0.26188686E+05  0.25860167E+05  0.36497102E+21 -0.22382683E-04  0.2575
5998E-21  0.25565946E-21  0.25755998E-21 -0.22382683E-04  0.26521737E-21  0.19324488E-21  0.20343380E-21 -0.21545303E-04  0.57573082E+16  0.72546330E-01  0.39981053E+00  0.72546330E-01  0.57573082E+16  0.
39735516E+00  0.39981053E+00  0.39735516E+00  0.56231557E+16
  -0.00088  700.0000    -73.66311585  0.36906067E+21  0.49347436E+04  0.26140162E+05  0.49347436E+04  0.36906067E+21  0.25823297E+05  0.26140162E+05  0.25823297E+05  0.36447145E+21 -0.23894574E-04  0.2544
7799E-21  0.28352559E-21  0.25447799E-21 -0.23894574E-04  0.29504345E-21  0.21088140E-21  0.22309387E-21 -0.22918721E-04  0.61662451E+16  0.78516921E-01  0.42624970E+00  0.78516921E-01  0.61662451E+16  0.
42369819E+00  0.42624970E+00  0.42369819E+00  0.60040577E+16
  -0.00088  750.0000    -73.66865606  0.36870841E+21  0.49084160E+04  0.26086737E+05  0.49084160E+04  0.36870841E+21  0.25780392E+05  0.26086737E+05  0.25780392E+05  0.36390571E+21 -0.25355784E-04  0.2531
5245E-21  0.31282663E-21  0.25315245E-21 -0.25355784E-04  0.32575977E-21  0.22850582E-21  0.24221285E-21 -0.24221592E-04  0.65651466E+16  0.84363890E-01  0.45153530E+00  0.84363890E-01  0.65651466E+16  0.
44888920E+00  0.45153530E+00  0.44888920E+00  0.63702891E+16
  -0.00088  800.0000    -73.67463901  0.36830739E+21  0.48871430E+04  0.26028025E+05  0.48871430E+04  0.36830739E+21  0.25731210E+05  0.26028025E+05  0.25731210E+05  0.36326904E+21 -0.26764355E-04  0.2532
5713E-21  0.34336830E-21  0.25325713E-21 -0.26764355E-04  0.35726002E-21  0.24594704E-21  0.26070611E-21 -0.25452271E-04  0.69530140E+16  0.90081852E-01  0.47559329E+00  0.90081852E-01  0.69530140E+16  0.
47285647E+00  0.47559329E+00  0.47285647E+00  0.67207365E+16
  -0.00083   50.0000    -73.63460788  0.37260205E+21  0.61107593E+04  0.22946119E+05  0.61107593E+04  0.37260205E+21  0.22154164E+05  0.22946119E+05  0.22154164E+05  0.31988878E+21  0.85731826E-05  0.4297
9228E-22  0.39630729E-21  0.42979228E-22  0.85731826E-05  0.57458467E-21 -0.12625719E-21  0.42899215E-22  0.16148230E-04  0.45714847E+15  0.80318416E-02  0.31283285E-01  0.80318416E-02  0.45714847E+15  0.
30552566E-01  0.31283285E-01  0.30552566E-01  0.43628859E+15
```

These data points have a periodicity according in column two and the value in coloum can extend to any higher value, say upto 1200.0000`

I want to make a for loop in such a way that it grep the value 100.000, 150.000, 200.0000 or any other value having pattern in colum two and then plot in a single plot.

as

```
plot "$i.dat" u 1:2  w l lt 1 lw 3
```

From the shell script I can do like this

```
for i in 100.0000 150.0000 200.0000
 grep '$i' case.data > $i.dat
```

and then I need to plot $i.dat in a single plot using  like below
    plot "$i.dat" u 1:2  w l lt 1 lw 3

Please read it carefully, The plot what I want can be obtained from a manual plot in the gnuplot as below but I want in a variable form.

```
 plot "100.0000.dat" u 1:2  w l lt 1 lw 3 ' \
 plot "150.0000.dat" u 1:2  w l lt 1 lw 3 ' \
 plot "200.0000.dat" u 1:2  w l lt 1 lw 3
```

In the next subplot similar plots will be done but the column number will be changed, i.e.

```
 plot "100.0000.dat" u 1:3  w l lt 1 lw 3 ' \
 plot "150.0000.dat" u 1:3  w l lt 1 lw 3 ' \
 plot "200.0000.dat" u 1:3  w l lt 1 lw 3
```

or

```
 plot "100.0000.dat" u 1:(($4*$5)/$3)  w l lt 1 lw 3 ' \
 plot "150.0000.dat" u 1:(($4*$5)/$3)  w l lt 1 lw 3 ' \
 plot "200.0000.dat" u 1:(($4*$5)/$3)  w l lt 1 lw 3
```

and there may be more similar plots.

```
So the finally what I like to get it
```

See below, in one plot there will $i (say I use it in plot (c).

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced size 20cm,20cm  color solid lw 3 "Times-Roman" 25
set output "output.eps"              be chansed as keep 1,1 at n1
set multiplot \
    layout m,n rowsfirst \      ## here m and n are variable that I will adjust according to my goal.
    title "{/:Bold=28 }" \
    margins screen 0.11,0.82,0.15,0.90 \
    spacing screen 0.00,0.00

set xticks ..
set yticks ..
set xrange ..
set yrange ..
set lable "(a)" font ....
plot "$i" u 1:5 w l lt .... , "$i" u 1:12 w l lt ....   ## Here and here-afrer $i will use all the values in a single subplot that grep from my data file as per colum 2.

unset ..
unset ..
set ..
set ..
set lable "(b)" font ....
plot "$i" u 1:($8*$9) w l lt .... , "$i" u 1:($24*$25) w l lt ....

unset ..
unset ..

set ..
set ..
set lable "(c)" font ....
plot "$i" u 1:($4*$5*$i/$16) w l lt .... , "$i" u ($4*$5*$i/$16) w l lt ....

unset ..
unset ..

set ..
set ..
set lable "(d)" font ....
plot "$i" u 1:11 w l lt .... , "$i" u 1:18 w l lt ....

and so on  where $i is a variable file name having data that to be plotted, 100.0000, 150.0000, 200.0000, ..... and so on.
```

Comment: Can't comment on the gnuplot portion of your Q, but I notice that `grep '$i' ...` should be `grep "$i" ....`. (note the change to dbl-quotes, single quotes will not allow the variable to be expanded to the value). Good luck.

Comment: Dear Shellter, Thanks for the response. I do not have any issue with " or '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly, there is no need for an external script.
You can also do it in gnuplot.
Use the ternary operator as filter:

For example: `($2==100 ? $2 : NaN)`

in words: 
if the column2-value is equal to 100, take the column2-value value, otherwise take NaN (which will not be plotted.)

**Edit:**
I'm still not sure whether I've understood your final goal. Let's try once more.

**Code:** (edited)

`YourFile.dat` (was a bit destorted in your post)

```
0.00098 50.0000 -73.62733500 0.37741253E+21 0.61856999E+04 0.23477516E+05 0.61856999E+04 0.37741253E+21 0.22799744E+05 0.23477516E+05 0.22799744E+05 0.32885992E+21 0.88623333E-05 0.9143842E-22 0.59361518E-21 0.91434842E-22 0.88623333E-05 0.76940601E-21 -0.11008087E-21 0.61205532E-22 0.18946967E-04 0.46510926E+15 0.84479535E-02 0.32276586E-01 0.84479535E-02 0.46510926E+15 0.1473355E-01 0.32276586E-01 0.31473355E-01 0.44827543E+15
0.00098 100.0000 -73.62549799 0.37578210E+21 0.65089174E+04 0.25164304E+05 0.65089174E+04 0.37578210E+21 0.24544833E+05 0.25164304E+05 0.24544833E+05 0.35067726E+21 0.51668308E-05 0.1764563E-21 0.80398976E-21 0.17649563E-21 0.51668308E-05 0.89345101E-21 0.73256391E-24 0.10266879E-21 0.16359894E-04 0.88915594E+15 0.15704246E-01 0.66816427E-01 0.15704246E-01 0.88915594E+15 0.5852810E-01 0.66816427E-01 0.65852810E-01 0.92442123E+15
0.00098 150.0000 -73.62497753 0.37191742E+21 0.64483669E+04 0.25884494E+05 0.64483669E+04 0.37191742E+21 0.25340696E+05 0.25884494E+05 0.25340696E+05 0.35980685E+21 -0.23512396E-05 0.1633744E-21 0.58153481E-21 0.16331744E-21 -0.23512396E-05 0.60771148E-21 0.50286216E-22 0.86373493E-22 0.50098427E-05 0.13431409E+16 0.20196300E-01 0.99364940E-01 0.20196300E-01 0.13431409E+16 0.7983721E-01 0.99364940E-01 0.97983721E-01 0.13754518E+16
0.00098 200.0000 -73.62563644 0.37048872E+21 0.62302191E+04 0.26197599E+05 0.62302191E+04 0.37048872E+21 0.25696216E+05 0.26197599E+05 0.25696216E+05 0.36375679E+21 -0.63534979E-05 0.1937109E-21 0.35080011E-21 0.19373109E-21 -0.63534979E-05 0.34652203E-21 0.74754878E-22 0.75715625E-22 -0.25397863E-05 0.18008807E+16 0.23385420E-01 0.13054336E+00 0.23385420E-01 0.18008807E+16 0.2878815E+00 0.13054336E+00 0.12878815E+00 0.18120888E+16
0.00098 250.0000 -73.62700262 0.37004605E+21 0.59702233E+04 0.26319789E+05 0.59702233E+04 0.37004605E+21 0.25845805E+05 0.26319789E+05 0.25845805E+05 0.36538123E+21 -0.87562569E-05 0.2350035E-21 0.21794599E-21 0.23508035E-21 -0.87562569E-05 0.20313466E-21 0.86523972E-22 0.74216616E-22 -0.69471421E-05 0.22540241E+16 0.26857802E-01 0.16135874E+00 0.26857802E-01 0.22540241E+16 0.5941431E+00 0.16135874E+00 0.15941431E+00 0.22455089E+16
0.00098 300.0000 -73.62885616 0.36987141E+21 0.57283989E+04 0.26353384E+05 0.57283989E+04 0.36987141E+21 0.25902439E+05 0.26353384E+05 0.25902439E+05 0.36594140E+21 -0.10680927E-04 0.2650374E-21 0.16112721E-21 0.26509374E-21 -0.10680927E-04 0.14526557E-21 0.94641866E-22 0.80057120E-22 -0.97718295E-05 0.27036601E+16 0.31147309E-01 0.19222339E+00 0.31147309E-01 0.27036601E+16 0.9021091E+00 0.19222339E+00 0.19021091E+00 0.26798788E+16
0.00098 350.0000 -73.63111766 0.36975138E+21 0.55256178E+04 0.26348308E+05 0.55256178E+04 0.36975138E+21 0.25919105E+05 0.26348308E+05 0.25919105E+05 0.36603300E+21 -0.12473836E-04 0.2799651E-21 0.14542677E-21 0.27991651E-21 -0.12473836E-04 0.13260173E-21 0.10349056E-21 0.91453794E-22 -0.11905859E-04 0.31506980E+16 0.36215123E-01 0.22310409E+00 0.36215123E-01 0.31506980E+16 0.2106737E+00 0.22310409E+00 0.22106737E+00 0.31144960E+16
0.00098 400.0000 -73.63376390 0.36962941E+21 0.53639569E+04 0.26326807E+05 0.53639569E+04 0.36962941E+21 0.25918318E+05 0.26326807E+05 0.25918318E+05 0.36591763E+21 -0.14220403E-04 0.2831619E-21 0.14955855E-21 0.28313619E-21 -0.14220403E-04 0.14127110E-21 0.11444368E-21 0.10676100E-21 -0.13748475E-04 0.35950954E+16 0.41845525E-01 0.25383427E+00 0.41845525E-01 0.35950954E+16 0.5177268E+00 0.25383427E+00 0.25177268E+00 0.35473558E+16
0.00098 450.0000 -73.63679316 0.36948970E+21 0.52383588E+04 0.26297916E+05 0.52383588E+04 0.36948970E+21 0.25908795E+05 0.26297916E+05 0.25908795E+05 0.36570139E+21 -0.15936631E-04 0.2795578E-21 0.16328981E-21 0.27957578E-21 -0.15936631E-04 0.15979750E-21 0.12755049E-21 0.12459804E-21 -0.15458011E-04 0.40362355E+16 0.47818758E-01 0.28423315E+00 0.47818758E-01 0.40362355E+16 0.8212874E+00 0.28423315E+00 0.28212874E+00 0.39763635E+16
0.00098 500.0000 -73.64021237 0.36932598E+21 0.51419673E+04 0.26264871E+05 0.51419673E+04 0.36932598E+21 0.25893531E+05 0.26264871E+05 0.25893531E+05 0.36542326E+21 -0.17621860E-04 0.2731103E-21 0.18212730E-21 0.27310103E-21 -0.17621860E-04 0.18309310E-21 0.14241596E-21 0.14390579E-21 -0.17090518E-04 0.44731808E+16 0.53962381E-01 0.31413040E+00 0.53962381E-01 0.44731808E+16 0.1196260E+00 0.31413040E+00 0.31196260E+00 0.43994976E+16
0.00098 550.0000 -73.64403198 0.36913386E+21 0.50682689E+04 0.26228510E+05 0.50682689E+04 0.36913386E+21 0.25873289E+05 0.26228510E+05 0.25873289E+05 0.36509452E+21 -0.19271791E-04 0.2662467E-21 0.20413816E-21 0.26623467E-21 -0.19271791E-04 0.20896167E-21 0.15856269E-21 0.16392041E-21 -0.18661811E-04 0.49048167E+16 0.60155238E-01 0.34336735E+00 0.60155238E-01 0.49048167E+16 0.4111935E+00 0.34336735E+00 0.34111935E+00 0.48147808E+16
0.00098 600.0000 -73.64826334 0.36890914E+21 0.50117933E+04 0.26188726E+05 0.50117933E+04 0.36890914E+21 0.25848018E+05 0.26188726E+05 0.25848018E+05 0.36471534E+21 -0.20881700E-04 0.2603843E-21 0.22846098E-21 0.26037843E-21 -0.20881700E-04 0.23645575E-21 0.17555634E-21 0.18411472E-21 -0.20173041E-04 0.53299487E+16 0.66317761E-01 0.37179746E+00 0.66317761E-01 0.53299487E+16 0.6945793E+00 0.37179746E+00 0.36945793E+00 0.52202929E+16
0.00098 650.0000 -73.65291720 0.36864759E+21 0.49682077E+04 0.26145083E+05 0.49682077E+04 0.36864759E+21 0.25817410E+05 0.26145083E+05 0.25817410E+05 0.36428161E+21 -0.22447322E-04 0.2561116E-21 0.25466854E-21 0.25615116E-21 -0.22447322E-04 0.26515795E-21 0.19303776E-21 0.20413756E-21 -0.21620851E-04 0.57473738E+16 0.72400690E-01 0.39928880E+00 0.72400690E-01 0.57473738E+16 0.9685170E+00 0.39928880E+00 0.39685170E+00 0.56142317E+16
0.00098 700.0000 -73.65800250 0.36834508E+21 0.49341868E+04 0.26097070E+05 0.49341868E+04 0.36834508E+21 0.25781111E+05 0.26097070E+05 0.25781111E+05 0.36378791E+21 -0.23965126E-04 0.2536118E-21 0.28250178E-21 0.25368118E-21 -0.23965126E-04 0.29486863E-21 0.21072212E-21 0.22376269E-21 -0.23001329E-04 0.61559302E+16 0.78375584E-01 0.42572703E+00 0.78375584E-01 0.61559302E+16 0.2319066E+00 0.42572703E+00 0.42319066E+00 0.59949801E+16
0.00098 750.0000 -73.66352576 0.36799775E+21 0.49072227E+04 0.26044213E+05 0.49072227E+04 0.36799775E+21 0.25738807E+05 0.26044213E+05 0.25738807E+05 0.36322879E+21 -0.25432369E-04 0.2528878E-21 0.31175849E-21 0.25281878E-21 -0.25432369E-04 0.32546713E-21 0.22838818E-21 0.24284943E-21 -0.24311455E-04 0.65545284E+16 0.84227621E-01 0.45101738E+00 0.84227621E-01 0.65545284E+16 0.4838335E+00 0.45101738E+00 0.44838335E+00 0.63611571E+16
0.00098 800.0000 -73.66949059 0.36760215E+21 0.48854421E+04 0.25986115E+05 0.48854421E+04 0.36760215E+21 0.25690254E+05 0.25986115E+05 0.25690254E+05 0.36259943E+21 -0.26847058E-04 0.2532757E-21 0.34224719E-21 0.25327757E-21 -0.26847058E-04 0.35684931E-21 0.24586617E-21 0.26131387E-21 -0.25549530E-04 0.69421686E+16 0.89950399E-01 0.47508540E+00 0.89950399E-01 0.69421686E+16 0.7235776E+00 0.47508540E+00 0.47235776E+00 0.67116424E+16
0.00093 50.0000 -73.62977019 0.37577464E+21 0.61553734E+04 0.23285918E+05 0.61553734E+04 0.37577464E+21 0.22570271E+05 0.23285918E+05 0.22570271E+05 0.32568177E+21 0.86963846E-05 0.7152652E-22 0.52597500E-21 0.71523652E-22 0.86963846E-05 0.70496949E-21 -0.11810836E-21 0.54664950E-22 0.17958746E-04 0.46250691E+15 0.83132601E-02 0.31933229E-01 0.83132601E-02 0.46250691E+15 0.1151664E-01 0.31933229E-01 0.31151664E-01 0.44409835E+15
0.00093 100.0000 -73.62798627 0.37476731E+21 0.64692520E+04 0.25007969E+05 0.64692520E+04 0.37476731E+21 0.24377200E+05 0.25007969E+05 0.24377200E+05 0.34845318E+21 0.53423675E-05 0.1713713E-21 0.75479441E-21 0.17133713E-21 0.53423675E-05 0.84146003E-21 -0.22647358E-23 0.96074049E-22 0.15893375E-04 0.89382697E+15 0.15795329E-01 0.67149566E-01 0.15795329E-01 0.89382697E+15 0.6214050E-01 0.67149566E-01 0.66214050E-01 0.92957900E+15
0.00093 150.0000 -73.62747497 0.37185376E+21 0.64337148E+04 0.25825768E+05 0.64337148E+04 0.37185376E+21 0.25278107E+05 0.25825768E+05 0.25278107E+05 0.35902397E+21 -0.22740554E-05 0.1676534E-21 0.55794765E-21 0.16760534E-21 -0.22740554E-05 0.58205475E-21 0.48726045E-22 0.82391713E-22 0.47808216E-05 0.13473342E+16 0.20257500E-01 0.99839308E-01 0.20257500E-01 0.13473342E+16 0.8484660E-01 0.99839308E-01 0.98484660E-01 0.13824225E+16
0.00093 200.0000 -73.62813929 0.37074725E+21 0.62240793E+04 0.26186874E+05 0.62240793E+04 0.37074725E+21 0.25684501E+05 0.26186874E+05 0.25684501E+05 0.36366013E+21 -0.63245921E-05 0.2022040E-21 0.34077370E-21 0.20224040E-21 -0.63245921E-05 0.33528141E-21 0.74144816E-22 0.73747595E-22 -0.26419524E-05 0.18038200E+16 0.23388093E-01 0.13092954E+00 0.23388093E-01 0.18038200E+16 0.2918874E+00 0.13092954E+00 0.12918874E+00 0.18176804E+16
0.00093 250.0000 -73.62950993 0.37038936E+21 0.59658990E+04 0.26329238E+05 0.59658990E+04 0.37038936E+21 0.25855227E+05 0.26329238E+05 0.25855227E+05 0.36556576E+21 -0.87397171E-05 0.2439671E-21 0.21417453E-21 0.24391671E-21 -0.87397171E-05 0.19847913E-21 0.86454004E-22 0.73212165E-22 -0.69822324E-05 0.22566213E+16 0.26845644E-01 0.16165253E+00 0.26845644E-01 0.22566213E+16 0.5971111E+00 0.16165253E+00 0.15971111E+00 0.22497456E+16
0.00093 300.0000 -73.63136730 0.37023446E+21 0.57244337E+04 0.26370893E+05 0.57244337E+04 0.37023446E+21 0.25920135E+05 0.26370893E+05 0.25920135E+05 0.36623411E+21 -0.10665783E-04 0.2727077E-21 0.15999813E-21 0.27270077E-21 -0.10665783E-04 0.14334688E-21 0.94817413E-22 0.79430659E-22 -0.97749483E-05 0.27064230E+16 0.31148260E-01 0.19246677E+00 0.31148260E-01 0.27064230E+16 0.9044950E+00 0.19246677E+00 0.19044950E+00 0.26834343E+16
0.00093 350.0000 -73.63363251 0.37011834E+21 0.55219962E+04 0.26368956E+05 0.55219962E+04 0.37011834E+21 0.25939889E+05 0.26368956E+05 0.25939889E+05 0.36636548E+21 -0.12457200E-04 0.2859081E-21 0.14534323E-21 0.28594081E-21 -0.12457200E-04 0.13176599E-21 0.10374811E-21 0.90961379E-22 -0.11894050E-04 0.31537973E+16 0.36237822E-01 0.22332990E+00 0.36237822E-01 0.31537973E+16 0.2128370E+00 0.22332990E+00 0.22128370E+00 0.31178832E+16
0.00093 400.0000 -73.63628270 0.36999656E+21 0.53608727E+04 0.26348637E+05 0.53608727E+04 0.36999656E+21 0.25940158E+05 0.26348637E+05 0.25940158E+05 0.36626387E+21 -0.14201523E-04 0.2876320E-21 0.14986192E-21 0.28769320E-21 -0.14201523E-04 0.14085974E-21 0.11470565E-21 0.10631587E-21 -0.13729077E-04 0.35985666E+16 0.41888424E-01 0.25406018E+00 0.41888424E-01 0.35985666E+16 0.5198667E+00 0.25406018E+00 0.25198667E+00 0.35508463E+16
0.00093 450.0000 -73.63931639 0.36985607E+21 0.52359300E+04 0.26320141E+05 0.52359300E+04 0.36985607E+21 0.25930902E+05 0.26320141E+05 0.25930902E+05 0.36605165E+21 -0.15915274E-04 0.2829019E-21 0.16372312E-21 0.28292019E-21 -0.15915274E-04 0.15956261E-21 0.12778551E-21 0.12417436E-21 -0.15433937E-04 0.40400685E+16 0.47876628E-01 0.28446661E+00 0.47876628E-01 0.40400685E+16 0.8234938E+00 0.28446661E+00 0.28234938E+00 0.39800681E+16
0.00093 500.0000 -73.64274063 0.36969117E+21 0.51402142E+04 0.26287162E+05 0.51402142E+04 0.36969117E+21 0.25915592E+05 0.26287162E+05 0.25915592E+05 0.36577383E+21 -0.17597906E-04 0.2754537E-21 0.18259769E-21 0.27549537E-21 -0.17597906E-04 0.18294720E-21 0.14261481E-21 0.14349843E-21 -0.17062815E-04 0.44773500E+16 0.54029595E-01 0.31437329E+00 0.54029595E-01 0.44773500E+16 0.1219283E+00 0.31437329E+00 0.31219283E+00 0.44034399E+16
0.00093 550.0000 -73.64656592 0.36949760E+21 0.50671478E+04 0.26250714E+05 0.50671478E+04 0.36949760E+21 0.25895174E+05 0.26250714E+05 0.25895174E+05 0.36544387E+21 -0.19245142E-04 0.2679438E-21 0.20461749E-21 0.26790438E-21 -0.19245142E-04 0.20887735E-21 0.15872565E-21 0.16352994E-21 -0.18630779E-04 0.49092895E+16 0.60227106E-01 0.34361874E+00 0.60227106E-01 0.49092895E+16 0.4135892E+00 0.34361874E+00 0.34135892E+00 0.48189407E+16
0.00093 600.0000 -73.65080369 0.36927118E+21 0.50112286E+04 0.26210761E+05 0.50112286E+04 0.36927118E+21 0.25869669E+05 0.26210761E+05 0.25869669E+05 0.36506268E+21 -0.20852261E-04 0.2615237E-21 0.22894553E-21 0.26150237E-21 -0.20852261E-04 0.23642687E-21 0.17568706E-21 0.18374226E-21 -0.20138688E-04 0.53346889E+16 0.66390898E-01 0.37205511E+00 0.66390898E-01 0.53346889E+16 0.6970504E+00 0.37205511E+00 0.36970504E+00 0.52246301E+16
0.00093 650.0000 -73.65546466 0.36900768E+21 0.49681140E+04 0.26166898E+05 0.49681140E+04 0.36900768E+21 0.25838796E+05 0.26166898E+05 0.25838796E+05 0.36462644E+21 -0.22415005E-04 0.2568558E-21 0.25516285E-21 0.25686558E-21 -0.22415005E-04 0.26518500E-21 0.19314055E-21 0.20378341E-21 -0.21583085E-04 0.57523434E+16 0.72472944E-01 0.39954993E+00 0.72472944E-01 0.57523434E+16 0.9710377E+00 0.39954993E+00 0.39710377E+00 0.56186973E+16
0.00093 700.0000 -73.66055778 0.36870295E+21 0.49344813E+04 0.26118629E+05 0.49344813E+04 0.36870295E+21 0.25802213E+05 0.26118629E+05 0.25802213E+05 0.36412980E+21 -0.23929854E-04 0.2540759E-21 0.28301226E-21 0.25408759E-21 -0.23929854E-04 0.29495343E-21 0.21080085E-21 0.22342621E-21 -0.22960037E-04 0.61610906E+16 0.78445803E-01 0.42598868E+00 0.78445803E-01 0.61610906E+16 0.2344481E+00 0.42598868E+00 0.42344481E+00 0.59995232E+16
0.00093 750.0000 -73.66608950 0.36835316E+21 0.49078313E+04 0.26065489E+05 0.49078313E+04 0.36835316E+21 0.25759609E+05 0.26065489E+05 0.25759609E+05 0.36356738E+21 -0.25394082E-04 0.2529193E-21 0.31229095E-21 0.25299193E-21 -0.25394082E-04 0.32561094E-21 0.22844604E-21 0.24252927E-21 -0.24266538E-04 0.65598409E+16 0.84295403E-01 0.45127671E+00 0.84295403E-01 0.65598409E+16 0.4863671E+00 0.45127671E+00 0.44863671E+00 0.63657280E+16
0.00093 800.0000 -73.67206337 0.36795486E+21 0.48863016E+04 0.26007083E+05 0.48863016E+04 0.36795486E+21 0.25710742E+05 0.26007083E+05 0.25710742E+05 0.36293437E+21 -0.26805713E-04 0.2532229E-21 0.34280603E-21 0.25327229E-21 -0.26805713E-04 0.35705226E-21 0.24590563E-21 0.26100832E-21 -0.25500918E-04 0.69475951E+16 0.90015851E-01 0.47533975E+00 0.90015851E-01 0.69475951E+16 0.7260759E+00 0.47533975E+00 0.47260759E+00 0.67161950E+16
0.00088 50.0000 -73.63219428 0.37418236E+21 0.61311700E+04 0.23109988E+05 0.61311700E+04 0.37418236E+21 0.22356056E+05 0.23109988E+05 0.22356056E+05 0.32270480E+21 0.86013329E-05 0.5525665E-22 0.46027248E-21 0.55256665E-22 0.86013329E-05 0.64014524E-21 -0.12353787E-21 0.48569415E-22 0.17028764E-04 0.45982260E+15 0.81727432E-02 0.31599025E-01 0.81727432E-02 0.45982260E+15 0.0841926E-01 0.31599025E-01 0.30841926E-01 0.44006283E+15
0.00088 100.0000 -73.63046660 0.37373730E+21 0.64305446E+04 0.24858504E+05 0.64305446E+04 0.37373730E+21 0.24216928E+05 0.24858504E+05 0.24216928E+05 0.34631993E+21 0.54702932E-05 0.1658544E-21 0.70371007E-21 0.16585544E-21 0.54702932E-05 0.78698173E-21 -0.48552261E-23 0.89262698E-22 0.15347130E-04 0.89850207E+15 0.15880313E-01 0.67465074E-01 0.15880313E-01 0.89850207E+15 0.6557114E-01 0.67465074E-01 0.66557114E-01 0.93449675E+15
0.00088 150.0000 -73.62997106 0.37178121E+21 0.64189202E+04 0.25769357E+05 0.64189202E+04 0.37178121E+21 0.25218083E+05 0.25769357E+05 0.25218083E+05 0.35827087E+21 -0.22175581E-05 0.1717257E-21 0.53312586E-21 0.17171257E-21 -0.22175581E-05 0.55495686E-21 0.47262063E-22 0.78279193E-22 0.45126183E-05 0.13515816E+16 0.20313928E-01 0.10030165E+00 0.20313928E-01 0.13515816E+16 0.8972467E-01 0.10030165E+00 0.98972467E-01 0.13892382E+16
0.00088 200.0000 -73.63064344 0.37100313E+21 0.62174829E+04 0.26177025E+05 0.62174829E+04 0.37100313E+21 0.25673768E+05 0.26177025E+05 0.25673768E+05 0.36357466E+21 -0.63016000E-05 0.2106518E-21 0.33004815E-21 0.21069518E-21 -0.63016000E-05 0.32327519E-21 0.73553769E-22 0.71720514E-22 -0.27600033E-05 0.18067844E+16 0.23389184E-01 0.13130795E+00 0.23389184E-01 0.18067844E+16 0.2958097E+00 0.13130795E+00 0.12958097E+00 0.18231754E+16
0.00088 250.0000 -73.63201945 0.37073193E+21 0.59611054E+04 0.26339008E+05 0.59611054E+04 0.37073193E+21 0.25865024E+05 0.26339008E+05 0.25865024E+05 0.36575452E+21 -0.87246423E-05 0.2527511E-21 0.21006243E-21 0.25272511E-21 -0.87246423E-05 0.19346653E-21 0.86377627E-22 0.72179562E-22 -0.70234263E-05 0.22592267E+16 0.26834422E-01 0.16194190E+00 0.26834422E-01 0.22592267E+16 0.6000327E+00 0.16194190E+00 0.16000327E+00 0.22539280E+16
0.00088 300.0000 -73.63388094 0.37059725E+21 0.57200805E+04 0.26388504E+05 0.57200805E+04 0.37059725E+21 0.25937968E+05 0.26388504E+05 0.25937968E+05 0.36652831E+21 -0.10650982E-04 0.2802615E-21 0.15871828E-21 0.28027615E-21 -0.10650982E-04 0.14127829E-21 0.94981648E-22 0.78791576E-22 -0.97803455E-05 0.27091876E+16 0.31151464E-01 0.19270788E+00 0.31151464E-01 0.27091876E+16 0.9068573E+00 0.19270788E+00 0.19068573E+00 0.26869618E+16
0.00088 350.0000 -73.63614996 0.37048515E+21 0.55180785E+04 0.26389620E+05 0.55180785E+04 0.37048515E+21 0.25960717E+05 0.26389620E+05 0.25960717E+05 0.36669836E+21 -0.12440648E-04 0.2919701E-21 0.14519602E-21 0.29192701E-21 -0.12440648E-04 0.13087283E-21 0.10399632E-21 0.90465017E-22 -0.11883078E-04 0.31568961E+16 0.36263232E-01 0.22355459E+00 0.36263232E-01 0.31568961E+16 0.2149884E+00 0.22355459E+00 0.22149884E+00 0.31212561E+16
0.00088 400.0000 -73.63880416 0.37036359E+21 0.53575705E+04 0.26370453E+05 0.53575705E+04 0.37036359E+21 0.25962009E+05 0.26370453E+05 0.25962009E+05 0.36661010E+21 -0.14182669E-04 0.2922978E-21 0.15013898E-21 0.29220978E-21 -0.14182669E-04 0.14042935E-21 0.11496157E-21 0.10587162E-21 -0.13709985E-04 0.36020363E+16 0.41934011E-01 0.25428552E+00 0.41934011E-01 0.36020363E+16 0.5219999E+00 0.25428552E+00 0.25219999E+00 0.35543290E+16
0.00088 450.0000 -73.64184230 0.37022231E+21 0.52333430E+04 0.26342343E+05 0.52333430E+04 0.37022231E+21 0.25953006E+05 0.26342343E+05 0.25953006E+05 0.36640177E+21 -0.15893927E-04 0.2862579E-21 0.16414594E-21 0.28622579E-21 -0.15893927E-04 0.15932400E-21 0.12801731E-21 0.12375407E-21 -0.15409973E-04 0.40438995E+16 0.47936929E-01 0.28469972E+00 0.47936929E-01 0.40438995E+16 0.8256954E+00 0.28469972E+00 0.28256954E+00 0.39837674E+16
0.00088 500.0000 -73.64527159 0.37005624E+21 0.51383471E+04 0.26309427E+05 0.51383471E+04 0.37005624E+21 0.25937643E+05 0.26309427E+05 0.25937643E+05 0.36612421E+21 -0.17573957E-04 0.2778495E-21 0.18306450E-21 0.27785495E-21 -0.17573957E-04 0.18280354E-21 0.14281249E-21 0.14309562E-21 -0.17035150E-04 0.44815165E+16 0.54098895E-01 0.31461586E+00 0.54098895E-01 0.44815165E+16 0.1242259E+00 0.31461586E+00 0.31242259E+00 0.44073774E+16
0.00088 550.0000 -73.64910260 0.36986122E+21 0.50659443E+04 0.26272890E+05 0.50659443E+04 0.36986122E+21 0.25917047E+05 0.26272890E+05 0.25917047E+05 0.36579299E+21 -0.19218494E-04 0.2695434E-21 0.20509650E-21 0.26954434E-21 -0.19218494E-04 0.20879750E-21 0.15888880E-21 0.16314438E-21 -0.18599755E-04 0.49137589E+16 0.60300709E-01 0.34386977E+00 0.60300709E-01 0.49137589E+16 0.4159799E+00 0.34386977E+00 0.34159799E+00 0.48230954E+16
0.00088 600.0000 -73.65334679 0.36963309E+21 0.50106041E+04 0.26232768E+05 0.50106041E+04 0.36963309E+21 0.25891307E+05 0.26232768E+05 0.25891307E+05 0.36540978E+21 -0.20822820E-04 0.2626163E-21 0.22943144E-21 0.26260163E-21 -0.20822820E-04 0.23640317E-21 0.17581883E-21 0.18337464E-21 -0.20104328E-04 0.53394250E+16 0.66465448E-01 0.37231234E+00 0.66465448E-01 0.53394250E+16 0.6995156E+00 0.37231234E+00 0.36995156E+00 0.52289612E+16
0.00088 650.0000 -73.65801490 0.36936762E+21 0.49679766E+04 0.26188686E+05 0.49679766E+04 0.36936762E+21 0.25860167E+05 0.26188686E+05 0.25860167E+05 0.36497102E+21 -0.22382683E-04 0.2575998E-21 0.25565946E-21 0.25755998E-21 -0.22382683E-04 0.26521737E-21 0.19324488E-21 0.20343380E-21 -0.21545303E-04 0.57573082E+16 0.72546330E-01 0.39981053E+00 0.72546330E-01 0.57573082E+16 0.9735516E+00 0.39981053E+00 0.39735516E+00 0.56231557E+16
0.00088 700.0000 -73.66311585 0.36906067E+21 0.49347436E+04 0.26140162E+05 0.49347436E+04 0.36906067E+21 0.25823297E+05 0.26140162E+05 0.25823297E+05 0.36447145E+21 -0.23894574E-04 0.2544799E-21 0.28352559E-21 0.25447799E-21 -0.23894574E-04 0.29504345E-21 0.21088140E-21 0.22309387E-21 -0.22918721E-04 0.61662451E+16 0.78516921E-01 0.42624970E+00 0.78516921E-01 0.61662451E+16 0.2369819E+00 0.42624970E+00 0.42369819E+00 0.60040577E+16
0.00088 750.0000 -73.66865606 0.36870841E+21 0.49084160E+04 0.26086737E+05 0.49084160E+04 0.36870841E+21 0.25780392E+05 0.26086737E+05 0.25780392E+05 0.36390571E+21 -0.25355784E-04 0.2531245E-21 0.31282663E-21 0.25315245E-21 -0.25355784E-04 0.32575977E-21 0.22850582E-21 0.24221285E-21 -0.24221592E-04 0.65651466E+16 0.84363890E-01 0.45153530E+00 0.84363890E-01 0.65651466E+16 0.4888920E+00 0.45153530E+00 0.44888920E+00 0.63702891E+16
0.00088 800.0000 -73.67463901 0.36830739E+21 0.48871430E+04 0.26028025E+05 0.48871430E+04 0.36830739E+21 0.25731210E+05 0.26028025E+05 0.25731210E+05 0.36326904E+21 -0.26764355E-04 0.2532713E-21 0.34336830E-21 0.25325713E-21 -0.26764355E-04 0.35726002E-21 0.24594704E-21 0.26070611E-21 -0.25452271E-04 0.69530140E+16 0.90081852E-01 0.47559329E+00 0.90081852E-01 0.69530140E+16 0.7285647E+00 0.47559329E+00 0.47285647E+00 0.67207365E+16
0.00083 50.0000 -73.63460788 0.37260205E+21 0.61107593E+04 0.22946119E+05 0.61107593E+04 0.37260205E+21 0.22154164E+05 0.22946119E+05 0.22154164E+05 0.31988878E+21 0.85731826E-05 0.4297228E-22 0.39630729E-21 0.42979228E-22 0.85731826E-05 0.57458467E-21 -0.12625719E-21 0.42899215E-22 0.16148230E-04 0.45714847E+15 0.80318416E-02 0.31283285E-01 0.80318416E-02 0.45714847E+15 0.0552566E-01 0.31283285E-01 0.30552566E-01 0.43628859E+15
```

**Code:**

```
### filter data
reset session

FILE = 'YourFile.dat'

# extract unique values from column2 and put it into an array
set table $Dummy
    plot FILE u 2 smooth freq
unset table
array myValues[|$Dummy|-6]   # array size -3 header and -3 footer lines
set table $Dummy2
    plot $Dummy u (myValues[$0+1] = $1) with table
unset table
print myValues
# alternatively you could set your array manually
# array myValues[16] =[50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800]

set datafile missing NaN
set offset 1e-5, 1e-5, 20,20
set xtics 1e-4

set key top left font ",6" out samplen 1

myTitle(i) = sprintf("%g",myValues[i])
set multiplot layout 2,2

    plot for [i=1:|myValues|] FILE u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $5 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i t myTitle(i), \
       for [i=1:|myValues|] '' u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $12 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i notitle

    plot for [i=1:|myValues|] FILE u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $8*$9 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i t myTitle(i), \
       for [i=1:|myValues|] '' u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $12 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i notitle

    plot for [i=1:|myValues|] FILE u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $4*$5*i/$16 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i t myTitle(i), \
       for [i=1:|myValues|] '' u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $12 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i notitle

    plot for [i=1:|myValues|] FILE u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $11 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i t myTitle(i), \
       for [i=1:|myValues|] '' u 1:($2==myValues[i] ? $18 : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc i notitle

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Theozh for the prompt response. I  will get back to you tomorrow after giving it a try. Sorry for dealy.

Comment: Dear Theozh, what is mean by datafile in the script?  I am having 3x2 multiplot so the y-range will be different for all plots.

Comment: So, you want a multiplot with (sub-)plots for each value (100,150,200,...)?

Comment: not like that, each (100,150,200,...) will be in  the same plot and for next plot the colum 2 will have different operation. I have updated the question now for a better understanding. I could not explained it properly in my original query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`, or other tools, to select/filter or otherwise *"massage"* your data prior to plotting.

So, here, I select rows where column2 is 50 then when it is 100.

```
set title 'Some Funky Title
set ylabel 'Your Y label'
set xlabel 'Your X label'
set yrange [25:125]
plot "<awk '$2==50 {print $1,$2}'  data.dat" using 1:2 title '50s' ,\
     "<awk '$2==100{print $1,$2}'  data.dat" using 1:2 title '100s'
```

[image]

---

Or, if you want to generate separate files in `bash` before starting `gnuplot`, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in 50 100 150; do
    awk -v c2=$d '$2==c2 {print $1,$2}'  data.dat > $d.csv
done
```

**Sample Output**

```
more 50.csv
-0.00098 50.0000
-0.00093 50.0000
-0.00088 50.0000
-0.00083 50.0000
```

and

```
more 100.csv
-0.00098 100.0000
-0.00093 100.0000
-0.00088 100.0000
```

---

Or, if you don't know the values in advance, you can just take the value in column 2 and make it into the output filename like this:

```
awk '{f=int($2); print $1,$2 > f ".csv" }' data.dat
```

Then your output files will be named `50.csv`, `100.csv` and so on according to whatever is in column 2.

Comment: Dear Mark, thanks for the response. I usually do like this but this time I am looking for a loop so that  I can make a standard script for future data analysis. If you do not get any point from my question, please  let me know so that I can explore more.

Comment: Ok. so use `awk` to generate the 50, 100, 150 data-sets as separate files before you start `gnuplot`. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: This is my other open question       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049022/how-to-use-grep-command-in-a-loop-in-gnuscript      where I want to use the for loop in the gnuscript. Please have a look at that query too.

Comment: Please try the final `awk` command in my answer above. It does what you want but much more simply and without any prior knowledge about the range of values being needed.

Comment: I could manage my other problem using VAR="`gawk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10}' case.data | grep 300.0000 > 300.dat ; gawk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10}' case.data | grep 500.0000 > 500.dat ; gawk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10}' case.data | grep 800.0000 > 800.dat`"    print VAR